# Reverse tethering hangs at netcfg (Cyanogen + Linux)

Tags: linux, tethering, reverse-tether

I'm trying to set up reverse-tethering from my Linux computer using the steps outlined in this post:

[Mathieu Carbou Photography Blog](http://blog.mycila.com/2010/06/reverse-usb-tethering-with-android-22.html)

However, when I get to the last step, "netcfg usb0 dhcp" hangs and/or times out. (It does *not* return a 'permission denied' error).

I'm running Cyanogenmod on a (rooted) Incredible, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 3):

Found the following on [How to get internet on your phone via USB | forum.xda-developers.com](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=793102&page=3)

> It is working now. After setting up ICS type in console emulator on
>   your phone:

```
ifconfig usb1 192.168.2.2 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
route add default gw 192.168.2.1 dev usb0
iptables -F
iptables -F -t nat
setprop net.dns1 8.8.8.8
setprop "net.gprs.http-proxy" ""
```